# Which is the most professional way to combine functions

Tags: java, methods, performance

I am taking a Java course and have a question about professionalism and efficiency.  I have read that it is best not to create temporary variables.

I have answered one of the quiz questions correctly as follows:

```
public void removeLowest(){

    remove(find(lowScore())); //doesn't really read very easily
}
```

The answer broke down each step like this:

```
public void removeLowest(){

    double low = lowScore();
    int lowScoreIndex = find(low);
    remove(lowScoreIndex);
}
```

Both versions accomplish the same task, but which is better?

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like a question for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You'll that method chaining in this manner is quite common and you're right in the fact that it can be difficult to read and debug.  One could argue that if the overhead of creating the temporary variables isn't impacting the performance of the application, then you shouldn't worry (greatly) about it

Comment: The second answer is easier to debug by putting System.out.println statements in the code.  It's probably easier for people to understand.

Comment: @Gilbert:righly said, but one can easily debug the first code sample using a debugger. using syso is really not required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of speed efficiency both are the same. However the first one saves some memory instead of allocating memory to store the returned values in the stack. In general one doesn't worry on using stack memory in such cases for two reasons. First, the stack is flexible and can store huge amount of temp data. Second, for later review of the code, giving the returned value of functions a name, makes the code more readable for the author and for other people modifying the code.

Comment: If memory serves the extra storage space needed for more variables should be on the order of a few bytes, so it really shouldn't be a concern.

Comment: Yes you are correct the amount of data stored is negligible, but theoretically it's still consuming more memory compared to the unsaved return data. @user3580294

Comment: Indeed it is. I never said anything to the contrary.

Answer (score 2):

It's a difficult question to answer, as there is some opinion for both arguments. However, if we look at the byte code for each:

**Remove Lowest no intermediates**

```
  public void removeLowest();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: aload_0       
       2: aload_0       
       3: invokespecial #2                  // Method lowScore:()D
       6: invokespecial #3                  // Method find:(D)I
       9: invokespecial #4                  // Method remove:(I)V
      12: return
```

**Lowest with Intermediates**

```
  public void removeLowest2();
Code:
   0: aload_0       
   1: invokespecial #2                  // Method lowScore:()D
   4: dstore_1      
   5: aload_0       
   6: dload_1       
   7: invokespecial #3                  // Method find:(D)I
  10: istore_3      
  11: aload_0       
  12: iload_3       
  13: invokespecial #4                  // Method remove:(I)V
  16: return
```

So you can see here that the intermediates do require more operations and storage. However, remember that the JVM is smart - so at runtime it will likely perform optimisations to this bytecode. Chances are if you call this a certain number of times it would inline the methods all into the same block anyway and remove the local storage.

In terms of your question, I'd go for readability over trying to write your code more compact at the cost of legibility. This is purely because that from your code -> byte code -> hotspot so much will happen to optimize this code that your main concern is writing the most maintainable code possible. As others have mentioned a few intermediate storage values that represent meaning cost very little in the bigger picture.

Comment: your answer is accurate. Personally I don't think compact code means less readability, unless some one really overdo(obfuscate) it. As long as identifier names are intuitive, even a compact code can be easy to understand and maintain. Also, splitting statements with obvious meanings don't help much. java already provides syntactical support to write compact code, implicit for loops, the try-with-resources, empty type parameters with constructors etc

Answer (score 1):

You are right - they both do the same thing!
However, the only difference is that by creating a variable, you also create a LocalVariableReference owned by the Thread running the method. This referenced to the returned Value returned by the inner method (such as the getLow() ). This means that naming the returned Values by declaring a variable for them takes more memory.
Nonetheless, it makes the code easier to read, and honestly, the space taken is very very minimal that it can be neglected! 
(It's only a reference to a Value -- very small data taken)

Bottom line: Do what is more comfortable for you to read and debug.

Answer (score 1):

For a small set of statements where variable names are intuitive even your first code example is perfectly fine. In second case the code is more verbose and easy to understand. (not saying verbosity == understanding).

`Efficiency`: you don't need to worry much about it at least in this particular case. correctly pointed out by Jim, JVM is more smarter than what we assume and may optimize where ever required. Also don't worry much about the space as long as you have put your variables/objects in correct scope. (method,class,instance). Remember when we say java program we are talking about `managed code`, So if you are favoring 1st for more efficiency I would say will not impact much.

`Professionalism`: here the second example is favored (as a practice demonstrator), There is one more aspect, `maintainability`. where similar usage may shine. (*maintainability doesn't only depend on this) 
There are languages which are less verbose and still work well for large code bases.